# Confusion on Htaccess redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

Suddenly GWT has reported over 50 404 errors for urls of this type

`http://example.com/abc/&sa=U&ved=0CCYQFjADahUKEwi_lo-6nInHAhXIoZQKHfkXDZw&usg=AFQjCNEfkaKtU35GolQ-KLlTBjIuoMejlQ`

I want to redirect these ugly and irrelevant urls to the actual URL i.e `http://example.com/abc/`

Will this code do the job

```
RedirectMatch ^/&sa$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

or should i use query string for the same??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^&]+)& /$1? [L,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. Your code works. Can i place this rule after my own RewriteRule like this  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
 RewriteRule ^([^&]+)& /$1? [L,NE,R=301]

Comment: Not sure why would you need `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]` rule. I suggest commenting out that rule and use this rule as first rule only.